# C# WinForm UI component for text and image

Tags: c#

I look for a UI Component for my C# WinForm application which can host just texts and images, I think the RichTextBox is too complicated and too much for my purpose, I need a simpler component in which I can enter texts or insert some images at some points. the markup language behind it also should be as simple to cover just the requirements above and parsing it must be simpler. Adding images to it also needs be simpler

Some disadvantages of RichTextbox for my purpose

- One may paste undesired contents to it which makes bug to the application and also makes the parsing difficult
- Parsing the source of it is not easy as a simple markup language is

Where I can find such a component?